# Including .eps figure in PDFLatex

Tags: pdftex, eps, epstopdf

This question has been asked a lot, but for reason I cannot get it to work. I'd like to include a `.eps` image in my document - I am using `pdflatex` in `TeXMaker`. Below is the input (I am providing the whole preamble incase there is some interference.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} %converting to PDF
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %how deep sections are numbers
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font={sf,footnotesize},labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %for large figures
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
\usepackage[defaultlines=4,all]{nowidow}

\includegraphics[scale=1]{/../model_1_2.eps}
```

The error I get is:

> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File `/model_1_2-eps-converted-to.pdf' not
>   found.See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.Type H
>    for immediate help.... .../../model_1_2.eps}

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Can you find the converted `pdf` file in that folder?

Comment: Do you mean a pdf of the image? No, I cannot.

Comment: Probably you need to launch pdflatex with the `--shell-escape` switch if you're under TeX Live, or `--enable-write18` under MiKTeX.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very technical - could you please explain how to do this/what this means?

Comment: You've done a couple of things: included an extension in the file name and giving a location 'up' from where your `.tex` file is. The first thing will mean that LaTeX will be looking for the 'wrong' file after conversion, and the second thing may block auto-conversion from EPS to PDF (security settings dependent).

Comment: So do you mean the image needs to be in the same file as the .tex file, and that I should not include the .eps extension?

Comment: The path of the image looks odd, it starts with `/..`, do you really mean the parent of the root?

Comment: @user3589557: Don't include the extension.

Comment: Start by putting the file in the same location as the .tex file and remove the .eps as well as the /../ parts of the path and see if that works. (The files (.tex & .eps) can be in different locations but this will help figure out the reason for the error.)

Comment: and what about VS code users? How can they launch pdflatex with that option?

Answer (score 26):

1. You shouldn't add the extension
2. The `/` at the beginning of the path looks wrong.

   You have a better chance with

   ```
   \includegraphics[scale=1]{../model_1_2}
   ```

   However:
3. You might not be allowed to work with a file that is one folder up, due to (reasonable) security restrictions disallowing this.

Comment: If you are using linux then install any **texlive-font-utils**. 

For debian based any distro like ununtu, just fire below command and everything working fine.



```sudo apt install texlive-font-utils ```

Comment: @shivangpatel I don't know how it works, but `texlive-font-utils` solved similar problem. Thank you, man!!

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `model_1_2.ps` to a PDF file using `ps2pdf`, and do not use the extension in `\includegraphics[]{path/model_1_2}`.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same error for `.eps` but with `TeXstudio`.
I was able to solve this error by "configuring paths" for the tool.

The `pdflatex` uses other tools such `epstopdf.exe`, but it was unable to find it. Configuring paths solved the issue.

See: Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Build

And set `Commands($PATH)` correctly to `<path>/miktex/bin/`

---

See if similar configuration is required in TeXMaker.

---

**Edit 1** Adding a configuration screenshot and simple working example.
[image: ![Screen-shot of TeXstudio configuration]

**Working example**

```
% Using 'journal' as a document class to compile the .tex file.
% Working is not related to this class.
\documentclass{journal}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{File1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set a path and just add

```
\graphicspath{{./example/}}
```

then something like

```
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{heart}
```

example

[image: This was the eps heart used as example]

secondly,
if you do not want to use set path for image.
just move the fold to the folder and just use

```
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{model_1_2}
```

This is the code i used with your code for image name heart.eps saved in folder name figures

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} %converting to PDF
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %how deep sections are numbers
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font={sf,footnotesize},labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %for large figures
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
\usepackage[defaultlines=4,all]{nowidow}
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{heart}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a niche answer, but I fixed this by adding ghostscript (`gs`) to my `PATH`. An OS which installs packages system-wide, like `apt-get` or `yum`, probably won't have this problem; but when using per-project dependencies (in my case with Nix) this might be the cause.

This particular error message was rather unhelpful; but when I tried running `epstopdf` straight from `bash` in the same environment (same `PATH`, etc.) then I got a more informative message saying that `gs` wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answers and the comments above, specifically that of [shivang patel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/191133/shivang-patel), I found the solution:

```
Just run the following two commands in turn:
```

```sh
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt install texlive-font-utils
```

This will install `ps2eps` which solves the issue.
**Important note:** I neither removed `.eps` from the end of the image's file name, nor changed the path of `eps` images to be the same as that of `.tex` file.
Finally, I compiled the `.tex` file in terminal using:

```sh
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -src  Presentation.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only pdf latex with package below :

```
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
```

And you should be add  --shell-escape in the pdflatex compillation mode as the next command :

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex

Also, you can use the psfrag (see the explication [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434761/164392)) if you want to tag something in the eps file.

see th full code below :

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 5pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{file.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use the graphicx package only
Example, \usepackage{graphicx}
and in \includegraphics you can use or not the image extension .eps(optional)

Answer (score -5):

Pdflatex does not handle PostScript input, i.e., no `.ps` nor `.eps`. Use some tool to translate into PDF, render as PNG. If possible, get directly into PDF.