# What does psfrag do, and can it be made to work with pdflatex?

Tags: psfrag

I'm picking up a document, thus far, created by someone else who is unavailable for questioning.

I have a vague idea what is trying to be accomplished with this:

```
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
\psfrag{F}{$F_c$}
\psfrag{M}{$M_0$}
\psfrag{V}{$V$}
\psfrag{Y}{$Y$}
\psfrag{X}{$X$}
\psfrag{T}{Thin film}
\psfrag{A}{Adhesive layer}
\psfrag{R}{Rigid surface}
\includegraphics{figure1a}
\end{figure}
```

(there are 2 more figures, b and c then)

"Fig. 1 Schematic description....." for a bottom of the page caption.

I can `latex` it without error, but when I try to `pdfltex` ... it I get an error message that states:

```
I could not locate the file with any of the extensions: .png, .pdf, .jpg, .mps, .jpg, .jbig2, .jb, .PNG, .PDF, .JPG, .JPEG, .JBIG2, .JB2 Try typing <return> to proceed.
```

After `latex`, `xdvi` file displays the desired figure, but there is text scrunched up on the left of the  page, to the left of the figure partially revealing "F_c" (in the proper format) through X on successive lines, then "Thin film, Adhesive layer", then "Rigid surface".  To the right of the figure is the figures' designator letter (a).

Just above to figure in the left margin above "F_c" is a cut-off word, ending ing 'g', I think "g replacements".

When I `pdflatex` in order to create a PDF file, then getting the aforementioned error message, I just , through it.  The resulting PDF is a blank page, save for the figures' letter designators, (a), (b), and (c) in a column down the center of the page with the "Fig.1..." caption at the bottom of the page.

The figure1a is in the same directory as the document files as figure1a.fig in addition to a figure1a.eps.

I've been able to come up with scant little help in the Leslie Lamport book.

Can you tell me what the `psfrag` business is all about?

I've imported figures in my own documents, but not in this fashion.  I hate to re-tool this one if I can create something better and learn a new technique in the process.

Comment: One issue here is that `pdflatex` can't handle `eps` files straightforwardly. It is looking for any of the listed file types. Convert the `eps` to a `pdf` first and try again.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/using-psfrag-with-pdflatex: you need to set up to run `latex` for the figures and then convert the appropriate parts to PDF format for `pdflatex`. That's best done using some automation.

Comment: So... adding \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} to the preamble will fix it? (I'm kind of new to LaTeX)    also, should I post commentary here or on the linked page?

Comment: @TommyK as Joseph pointed out, `psfrag` is intended to be used along the `latex` route. Not sure if the `[pdf]` workaround has any effect on `psfrag`

Comment: So, I added the \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} to no avail.  I'm still confused.

Comment: So... it appears that the psfrag may only work in a Post Script  environment.  Which, I think the X viewer is, however I am suspecting that it is not compatible with generating a .pdf document. Am I correct?  If so, I think I may need to re-tool the graphics on this one.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Why is there no `pdffrag` package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27475/5764)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

The [psfrag package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) is used to remove labels and other text from `.eps` graphics and replace them with `LaTeX` labels. This can be used to ensure that fonts in figures are consistent with those in the main body of the document, regardless of whether your graphics software can access them. It is particularly useful for inserting formulae and symbols, since a label in the `eps` file can be replaced by (more or less) arbitrary `LaTeX` code. In this example, the word 'typography' is replaced by an italic version in the current font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=70pt]{small}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\psfrag{typography}{\textit{typography}}
\includegraphics[width=70pt]{small}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The file 'small.eps' is as follows:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%Title: test.eps
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 100 50
/Times-Roman findfont
15 scalefont
setfont
20 20 moveto
(typography) show
showpage
%EOF
```

[image: frag]

However, as you have discovered, `psfrag` only works if you compile via `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`; it won't work with `pdflatex`. There is a package called [pstool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstool) which works around this problem. Provided that shell escape is enabled, this version of the example will work with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=70pt]{small.eps}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\psfragfig*[width=70pt]{small}{\psfrag{typography}{\textit{typography}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For pdflatex one can also load `psfrag` and `auto-pst-pdf` and use `psfrag`'s original syntax. (This also requires shell-escape to be enabled.)

Comment: pstool indeed works great, but you should be careful not to write the file extension in the first mandatory argument of \psfragfig and to run pdflatex with the -shell-escape command line option.

Answer (score 3):

To use psfrag with pdflatex, the first things is to make

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

In pdflatex compelation you should be add "--shell-escape %.tex" like the text befor.

And after you should be load auto-pst-pdf and psfrag

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 5pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\begin{psfrags}
    \psfrag{G}{0.2}
    \psfrag{H}{0.15}
    \includegraphics[width=15cm,height=12cm]{aeee.eps}
\end{psfrags}
\end{document}
```